# Who controls the twitter account?

Tags: support

History.SE has a twitter account, but who controls it? Is it controlled by the moderators or is it automated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was news to me, but sure enough, [it does](https://twitter.com/StackHistory). @StackHistory.

Based on the content I'm seeing there, it looks like its some kind of bot, just posting new questions that are positively moderated. [This question on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79455/stackapps-twitter-account) seems to confirm that.

Comment: FWIW, I'm on twitter too, but you probably won't be very interested in my feed unless we happen to share a home town, church, or favorite futbol club.

Comment: It *does* what? Also, out of curiosity, what is your twitter account? :-)